# How do I solve NameError: name 'threading' is not defined in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following program, and nothing else, python 3.3. When I run it. I get

```
NameError: name 'threading' is not defined
```

I googled but none of the answers given explain my situation. any clues? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Utilities
import os
import sys
import getopt
import time
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

_db_lock=threading.Lock()
```

I also tried

```
_db_lock=threading.Lock
```

Comment: just import threading

Comment: You should *always* add the complete traceback of your error when posting a question with an exception.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must import threading. Add the following to the beginning of your file:

```
import threading
```

The error originates from the line:

```
_db_lock=threading.Lock()
```

That's because you've used `from threading import Thread`, but you've never actually introduced `threading` in to the local namespace. So far there's only `Thread` (even though technically the import is there, it's just not in the namespace, you cannot use it).

If for some reason you wish to keep `threading` from 'polluting' your namespace, import the `Lock` in the same manner as you've imported `Thread`, like so:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
_db_lock = Lock()
```